# What value should I use for Content-Length of an POST HTTP request?

Tags: java, android, http, http-headers

I am trying to send HTTP request. Currently I am stuck on adding Content-Length property: I have

```
httpPost.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=utf-8");
httpPost.addHeader("Content-Length", ""+json.length() );
```

If i comment last line (content-length) server returns me error that I miss smth, I last line stays uncommented - then I catch an exception when trying to do

```
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
```

Please, tell me what am I doing wrong with setting headers.

PS I am sending easy JSON object

```
 JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
 jsonObject.accumulate("phone", phone);
```

My full code snippet of post metod:

```
public static JSONObject POST(String url, String phone){
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String result = "";
        try {

            // 1. create HttpClient
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            // 2. make POST request to the given URL
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            String json = "";

            // 3. build jsonObject
            Log.d("ANT", "JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(); PHONE:"+phone);
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.accumulate("phone", phone);

            // 4. convert JSONObject to JSON to String
            json = jsonObject.toString();

            // 5. set json to StringEntity
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);

            // 6. set httpPost Entity
            httpPost.setEntity(se);

            Log.d("ANT", "json"+json.length());

            // 7. Set some headers to inform server about the type of the content

            httpPost.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;");
//            httpPost.addHeader("Content-Length", ""+json.length() );


            // 8. Execute POST request to the given URL
            Log.d("ANT", "httpPost:"+getStringFromInputStream(httpPost.getEntity().getContent()));
            for (Header s : httpPost.getAllHeaders())
                Log.i("ANT", "header::"+s.getName() + ":"+s.getValue());


            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

            // 9. receive response as inputStream
            inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
            Log.d("ANT", "httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();");

            // 10. convert inputstream to string
            if (inputStream != null) {
                result = getStringFromInputStream(inputStream);
                Log.d("ANT", "getStringFromInputStream : "+result);
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result);
                Log.d("ANT", "JSONObject");
                return obj;
            }
            else
                result = "Did not work!";

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Log.d("ANT", "ClientProtocolException : "+ e.getLocalizedMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("ANT", "IOException:"+ e.getLocalizedMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("ANT", "Exception:"+ e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        // 11. return result
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you elaborate on what the server error code is and a stack trace when the exception occurs?

**Edit:**

I tried some part of your code. I did not set the Content-Length (since this should be done automatically):

```
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        post("http://www.baidu.com","+8912345");
    }

    public static JSONObject post(String url, String phone){
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String result = "";

        try {
            // 1. create HttpClient
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            // 2. make POST request to the given URL
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            String json = "";

            // 3. build jsonObject
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.accumulate("phone", phone);

            // 4. convert JSONObject to JSON to String
            json = jsonObject.toString();

            // 5. set json to StringEntity
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);

            // 6. set httpPost Entity
            httpPost.setEntity(se);

            // 7. Set some headers to inform server about the type of the content
            httpPost.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;");

            // 8. Execute
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

            // 9. receive response as inputStream
            inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            System.out.println("ClientProtocolException : "+e.getLocalizedMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IOException:"+ e.getLocalizedMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception:"+ e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

I used wireshark and could verify that the following request is going to baidu:

> POST / HTTP/1.1
>   Accept: application/json 
>   Content-Type: application/json; 
>   Content-Length: 20 
>   Host: www.baidu.com 
>   Connection: Keep-Alive 
>   User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.3.6 (java 1.5)
>
> {"phone":"+8912345"}

This shows that the request is sent properly, which means the client side seems to be fine. That's why I would suggest to check the server side for errors. As I already mentioned I think you should use tcpdump or wireshark to check the traffic between client and server. This might give you a better understanding of what is going wrong.

Comment: I have ClientProtocolException with e.getLocalizedMessage():null; if httpPost.addHeader("Content-Length", ""+json.length() ); is uncommented.
If it is commmented, server gives ":-31,"Message":"Operation denied. Please contact us"

Comment: Can you show the code snippet how you form the post request? Also, does json.length() return sth greater than 0? Further, you could also try to verify with tcpdump or wireshark if the request you send actually contains the correct header and content data.

Comment: json.length() returns 24 actually. Will add in a minute code

Comment: Great answeir, thanks! I would certainly google about these tools!